# Mapping a list in a list with MapStruct without customize interface

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am trying to map an object what has List inside List with MapStruct. I can mapping parent list but nested list becoming null and cannot mapping.

The JSON like this;

```
req={
    ...
    SearchCriteriaList:[
       {key:"mykey1",values:["val1","val2"]},
       {key:"mykey2",values:["val3","val4"]}
    ]
    ...

}
```

I am mapping parent List with this code;

```
@Mapping(source="searchCriteriaList", target="searchCriteriaList")
```

And also I want to mapping ;

```
@Mapping(source="searchCriteriaList.values", target="searchCriteriaList.values")
```

Is there a way mapping values with with an annotation and witout customize interface.

Comment: The lists are same or different ?

Comment: The `SearchCriteriaList` isn't really a `List` but rather a `Map` as it has a `key` and `value`. Depending on what you want to map it to, it is basically impossible to tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AndreyChertok they are nested list. I can map searchCriteriaList. Also I want map searchCriteriaList.values too. There is no problem "key" object it's mapping my first mapping annotation. But nested lists dont work.

Comment: @displayname so do you need map some nested object inside list of a map, right ?

Comment: @AndreyChertok, Yes

Comment: @displayname you provide not enough information, but from that point what I see you need just implemented apart method of mapping that object inside of a list to another object and your issue should resolve